# Choice of Wifi network

Tags: wireless, 13.10

At home there are two wireless access points and in a certain room the signal strength of the first one is very low while the signal of the second one is relatively stronger.

However, Ubuntu insists on trying to connect to the first access point in the order they were added irrespective of signal strength.

Is there a way to make sure Ubuntu selects the access point **automatically** on the basis of signal strength?

#### EDIT

The access points have different SSIDs.

Comment: Do the two access points have different names? If so you may be able to choose manually depending on which room you are at. I had created two access points with the same name in my home (using two routers) but it didn't quite work the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try setting the MAC address of the access point you wish to connect to in Network Manager under BSSID. Check off 'Connect Automatically.' Please see: http://img.xrmb2.net/images/647404.png  You can find the MAC address here:

```
iwconfig
```

For example:

```
wlan0 IEEE 802.11abgn ESSID:"GBR1"
Mode:Managed Frequency:2.452 GHz Access Point: 88:D7:99:41:54:EE
Bit Rate=18 Mb/s Tx-Power=15 dBm
Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
```

Therefor, if I wanted to try to get Network Manager to prefer the access point GBR1, I'd set the BSSID to 88:D7:99:41:54:EE.