# Issue with choice of AP when connecting to university wifi on Lenovo X230/Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo, intel-wireless

I have a Lenovo X230 running Ubuntu 16.04.2 and it has some minor issues when using the eduroam wifi at my University. The setup of the wifi is done according to the [official guidelines](https://innsida.ntnu.no/wiki/-/wiki/English/Eduroam+on+Linux), but I often have a weak Wifi signal strength, which leads to a slow connection.

I've used a small python script which uses `iwlist` to scan for the available APs nearby. The output is:

```
eduroam     00:81:C4:B7:41:C0    57 %     -70 dBm   2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
eduroam     FC:5B:39:AB:A3:30    50 %     -75 dBm   2.437 GHz (Channel 6) 
eduroam     FC:5B:39:B5:81:50    56 %     -71 dBm   2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
eduroam     00:81:C4:E4:24:50    63 %     -66 dBm   2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
*eduroam*     00:81:C4:E4:24:DF    34 %     -86 dBm   5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
eduroam     00:81:C4:E4:24:5F    50 %     -75 dBm   5.18 GHz (Channel 36)
eduroam     00:81:C4:F9:7A:EF    37 %     -84 dBm   5.18 GHz (Channel 36) 
eduroam     FC:5B:39:AB:A3:3F    37 %     -84 dBm   5.2 GHz (Channel 40)
eduroam     FC:5B:39:77:4F:FF    31 %     -88 dBm   5.2 GHz (Channel 40)
eduroam     00:81:C4:B7:41:CF    57 %     -70 dBm   5.2 GHz (Channel 40)
eduroam     FC:5B:39:B8:35:9F    37 %     -84 dBm   5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
eduroam     00:81:C4:F1:6A:9F    31 %     -88 dBm   5.24 GHz (Channel 48)
```

Where * eduroam * is the one I'm currently connected to. This of course changes, depending on where I am, but I quite often notice that I am connected to a weak AP which slows down my connection when APs which are stronger(closer?) are available.

So my questions are:

- what factors governs the choice of AP, if not signal strength?
- where can this be overridden in Ubuntu?
- Is it possible to manually set up different connections for my usual spots with a "non-roaming" AP?

I've already seen this [Choice of Wifi network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380834/choice-of-wifi-network) , but this does not answer my questions or let me know how to set up different connections on the same ESSID.

You can see a dump of my wifi info here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/24046624/

Answer (score 1):

You can lock your computer to a specific access point by placing the mac address of a specific access point into the BSSID field in your connection profile.

[image]